# Is it true that $\Gamma^{-1}(x) \in O(\log x/\log \log x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, asymptotics

Here, $\Gamma^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse of the gamma function. Or, if you prefer, $\Gamma^{-1}(x) = \min \{y : y! \geq x\}$. I saw a claim that $\Gamma^{-1}(x) \in O(\log x/\log\log x)$ but I'm not sure how to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $y = \Gamma^{-1}(x)$, so that $x = \Gamma(y)$, as $x \to \infty$ we have $y \to \infty$. By Stirling's formula we then have

$$
\log x \sim y \log y
$$

and, taking logarithms again,

$$
\log\log x \sim \log y
$$

as $x \to \infty$. Combining these two formulas yields

$$
\Gamma^{-1}(x) = y \sim \frac{\log x}{\log y} \sim \frac{\log x}{\log\log x}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Does this approach also yield a lower bound?

Comment: @SuperSmart, it yields an exact asymptotic, not just an upper or lower bound.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Thanks.